# Prevent start of block to move when tabbing block on Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I've been using this editor for quite some time and I must say I am really impressed with it overall except for this little annoying thing: http://screencast.com/t/xpzD44qL5PYr

In that video you can see that when you indent a block, the starting point also moves which is quite annoying when you cut and paste it somewhere else. Do we have a setting to change this? Thanks. Still a great editor! :D

Answer (score 0):

It's doable with a plugin (though there could also be a setting I'm not aware of.

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class MyIndentCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        view = self.view
        view.run_command("indent")
        cursors = view.sel()
        new_cursors = []
        for cursor in cursors:
            new_cursor = view.line(cursor)
            if cursor.b < cursor.a:
                temp = new_cursor.a
                new_cursor.a = new_cursor.b
                new_cursor.b = temp
            new_cursors.append(new_cursor)
        view.sel().clear()
        for cursor in new_cursors:
            view.sel().add(cursor)
```

Look through the default key bindings and see what key combinations and context apply the `indent` command. Then simply add those to your user key binding, substituting the command `indent` for `my_indent`.

Comment: i believe there should be a setting for this. anyways, thanks for this.. didn't try this though.. it's too trivial to make a plugin with..